# Need mySQL query to check for updated birthday in another table

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am downloading data from a 3rd party datasource and one field is a contact's birthday, which may be blank i.e. 0000-00-00.  My users have the option of entering the contact's birthday if they choose, and I hold this is in a *separate* table because if I updated the original table, whenever the user refreshed with the original datasource, all updated birthdays would be erased.

I now want to find all birthdays in next 30 days.  This works on the first (original datasource) table:

```
    $BirthdayResults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Connections WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND (DATE_FORMAT(ContactBirthday, '%m%d') BETWEEN '$sCurrentDate' AND '$sDateOneMonthAdded')");
```

So I am wondering if mySQL can handle this type of logic:

```
$BirthdayResults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Connections WHERE UserID='$UserID'... 
 AND IF ContactBirthday IN Connections = '0000-00-00' 
 CHECK OTHER_BIRTHDAY_TABLE AND USE THIS BIRTHDAY IF IT EXISTS 
 WHERE Connections.ContactID=OTHER_BIRTHDAY_TABLE.ContactID
```

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Connections LEFT JOIN OTHER_BIRTHDAY_TABLE USING(ContactID)
WHERE  UserID='$UserID'
   AND DATE_FORMAT(
         IF(
           Connections.ContactBirthday = '0000-00-00',
           OTHER_BIRTHDAY_TABLE.BIRTHDAY,
           Connections.ContactBirthday
         ),
         '%m%d'
       ) BETWEEN '$sCurrentDate' AND '$sDateOneMonthAdded'
```

However, `NULL` would be more appropriate than `0000-00-00` in this situation; in which case one could use MySQL's [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) functions instead:

```
       DATE_FORMAT(
         IFNULL(Connections.ContactBirthday, OTHER_BIRTHDAY_TABLE.BIRTHDAY),
         '%m%d'
       )
```